# How to get SharePoint survey graphical view results using API call?

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-view, sharepoint-rest-api, survey-list, api

I have create the survey list in SharePoint 2013.i have added some questions in it.i need to get the graphical response view using API call or programmatically.
I need to display my own view in another page.
I have tried API call for getting

1) Questions : `http://siteURL/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('SurveyList')/fields?$filter=(CanBeDeleted eq true)`

2) All Items view `http://SiteURL/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('SurveyList')/items`

but the graphical view page i am not able to get the results.

Please suggest any idea.

Comment: You need to create your own Chart from the values you get from 2) APIs only get you access to Data, not to how SharePoint presents Data

Answer (score 0):

You can use `http://SiteURL/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('SurveyList')/items` and do your own maths.